# Function Pop Up appears twice

Tags: php, jquery, forms, function, recaptcha

Good morning!

I have implemented the following on my website to prevent a user from submitting a form without checking the captcha. It's working awesome, but the issue I have is that the same alert message appears twice. Pop's up once, dismiss it, then it pops up a second time, when you dismiss the message the second time it stays gone. I'd like it to stay gone the first time a user dismisses it, not the second time. Any suggestions?

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
  jQ('#login_form').submit(function(event) {
     var recaptcha = jQ("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
     if ( recaptcha === "" ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please check the recaptcha");
     }
  });
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: If I change event.preventDefault(); to event.stopPropagation(); when the user clicks ok to dismiss ( twice still ) the message, it then allows them to bypass check marking the captcha.

Comment: is it always that this event is getting called twice?

Comment: Yes, so far no matter what I have done, the message "please check the recaptcha" appears twice. It's working the way I want it to, to prevent the user from submitting the form without validating the captcha, but the alert message has to be dismissed twice if there is no captcha checked.

Comment: so maybe just display this alert once, and set some flag variable to prevent displaying it the 2nd time

Comment: any suggestions on what variable I should try to prevent it from coming up the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my own issue by adding val1.value = ""; :

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
  jQ('#login_form').submit(function(event) {
     var recaptcha = jQ("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
     if ( recaptcha === "" ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please check the recaptcha");
        val1.value = "";
     }
  });
});</script>
```